# how to change orientation of viewController that is not in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

in the example below is there a way to make the orientation of readerVC to be portrait and landscape.

```
func loadReader(filePaht : String)  {

            let document = ReaderDocument(filePath: filePaht, password: nil)
            if document != nil {
                let readerVC = ReaderViewController(readerDocument: document)
                readerVC?.delegate = self
                readerVC?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
                readerVC?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(readerVC!, animated: true)

                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the supported interface orientations:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

Or you can `return .allButUpsideDown`, `return .portrait` - whatever you want to specify.